# Flume Architecture: Events passing to Channel

Tags: hadoop, architecture, interceptor, flume, channel

Using the source SpoolDir, do flume interceptors intercept all events from a file before sending it to the channel or do they intercept and send to the channel one at a time?

Comment: Isn't the flush size of the source a configuration option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sent in batches

`batchSize` defaults to 100

> Granularity at which to batch transfer to the channel

Comment: Thank you! I am new with Flume, it helps a lot!